# Handling server sending a lot of messages to a client

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, tcp, tcpclient

I am sending a lot of messages one after another in a loop with TcpClient and sometimes I seem to get all of the messages and sometimes only 1. When I send only one message it works correctly. It only seems to occur when I send a lot of packets really fast.

```
public StreamWriter writer;

public void WriteListToClient(List<string> messages)
{
    foreach (var message in messages)
    {
        this.writer.WriteLine(message);
        this.writer.Flush();
    }
}
```

and recieving the messages with the following client code

```
public TcpClient client;
public StreamReader reader;

while (true)
        {
            if (this.client != null)
            {
                if (this.client.Available != 0)
                {
                    var message = this.reader.ReadLine();

                    if (message == null || message == "")
                    {
                        return;
                    }

                    Debug.Log(message);

                    this.commands.Enqueue(message);
                }
            }
        }
```

Is there any way to fix this or am I using a wrong method of sending and receiving data

Comment: TCP is send and acknowledge. And arguably slow because it waits. UDP is send and hope and able to handle more rapid data. Hence nearly every game you play (that is online) uses udp however it may not always arrive so there are other things that need to be considered because of it eg how to tell you missed something and recover.

Comment: Yeah and I still lose the data over the network or I don't catch it successfully

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want this to work continously, so you should probably not return if there is no data.

```
if (message == null || message == "")
{
    continue;
}
```

Also you should not use

```
while(true)
```

like that because that will probably lock your application on execution, try changing that method to coroutine with

```
yield return new WaitForSeconds(dt);
```

inside loop

Comment: I am using another thread for reading the data from the server, so it won't be a problem. About the return, yes I swapped it out with continue. But I still lose messages over the network.

Comment: You can’t lose messages if it’s tcp thet are guaranteed to be sent and received.

Comment: Yeah theoretically, but it seems I am not handling them correctly on the client side. And I lose a lot of data.